# Apache alias not working correctly

Tags: server, php, apache2, alias

I have added these lines in my 000-default virtual host file:

```
Alias /antoniocs/project "/home/antoniocs/www/project"
<Directory "/home/antoniocs/www/project">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

/home/antoniocs/www/project Contains a drupal website

If I go to:

localhost/antoniocs/project

This works out fine. I see everything perfectly.
But when I try to click on a link that takes me, for example, to:

localhost/antoniocs/project/category

I get this error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL
>   /home/antoniocs/www/project/index.php
>   was not found on this server.

Is this not processing the .htaccess that is in the project folder? What am I doing wrong???

NOTE: I also find it strange that it's giving me a file path and not an url path

Running on Apache 2.2.16 (with mod rewrite) Ubuntu 10.10 php 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.1

EXTRA NOTE: 
For those that don't know drupals htaccess, it redirects everything to index.php?q=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a very old post but I thought [this information I found on another StackExchange site might be of assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254403/url-rewriting-doesnt-work-if-web-site-is-accessed-via-alias-directory).

When using an `alias` in your apache configuration you also need to use `RewriteBase` in your .htaccess file that's the same as the alias.

```
Alias /antoniocs/project "/home/antoniocs/www/project"
<Directory "/home/antoniocs/www/project">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Requires that you include...

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /antoniocs/project

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I actually noticed it on a project because there was a rewrite going on with images/js/css and all my supplemental files were not loading.

Comment: Thank you Vagari.  You saved me.  I was experiencing a similar issue with cakephp 3.0.  I was stuck for a week on it.  I had to add RewriteBase to my .htaccess file in my app directory and in my webroot directory.  Thx again.

Comment: This is the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a rewrite is taking place in the wrong location. For example, the webserver is trying to find the URL `/home/antoniocs/www/project/index.php` instead of the local file by the same path. Perhaps check the Drupal installation itself? You can check what the server thinks by looking at the requests for redirection using something like *curl*:

```
curl -I http://localhost/antoniocs/project/category
```

See if code 301 or 302 is returned, and that may help narrow down the problem. E.g.:

```
$ curl -I http://www.outflux.net/blog
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
...
Location: http://www.outflux.net/blog/
```

Comment: The code returned is 404 :(

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also enable `userdir` module of apache. So that you don't have to create an alias to access the codes that resides in your home directory

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
cd ~
mkdir public_html
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Put your code under this public_html and you can access it by http://localhost/~username or http://ipaddress/~username (for example: http://localhost/~aneesh)

You can change the directory name(public_html) by editing the conf file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf`

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I edited the userdir.conf and changed public_html to www but apache does not seem to reload the module configurations. Do I need to disable and enable the module for the new configurations to take effect? Also I tried putting a php file in the public_html (just to test it) and it sent me the file instead of running the php file

Comment: Ok I figured out what the problem was I forgot to change the UserDir. I keep having the same problem with clean urls, apparently the .htaccess is not being read

Comment: i assume that you are running php. Just have a look at /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf. and comment the following section if it is not already done. 

 <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            php_admin_value engine Off
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1):

See if anything here can help: https://drupal.org/node/163915, your problem may have something to do with the  AllowOverride statement in; /etc/apache2/sites-available/default